# how can this keyword used here to call toString() method without using . operator

Tags: java

```
public class potpie {

    private int month;

    private int day ;

    private int year;

    public potpie(int m,int d,int y) {

        month=m;

        day=d;

        year=y;

        System.out.printf("The constructor for this is"+this);

    }
    public String toString() {

        return String.format("%d/ %d/ %d/", month,year,day);

    }

}

class apples {

    public static void main(String args[])

    {

    potpie x= new potpie(4,5,6);

    }

}
```

Comment: `this` represent current **instance**.

Comment: @Meepo it's not the print: it's the +

Comment: Why so many downvotes?  This is actually quite a reasonable question.

Comment: @MauricePerry you are correct, I was just generalizing it, but my mistake. Concatenation says, hey, all of this should be a string, let me turn it into a string. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic is in the `+` operator for `String`s.  When you add a `String` to an `Object` using `+`, the JVM calls the `toString` method on the `Object`, to work out what `String` to concatenate.

Also, `this` represents the instance on which the current method is being run, so by adding `this` to a `String` with the `+` operator, you get `toString` called on the current instance.

From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

> **15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +**
>
> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

[and further](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)

> **5.1.11. String Conversion**
>
> Any type may be converted to type String by string conversion.
>
> A value x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance creation expression (§15.9):
>
> - If T is boolean, then use new Boolean(x).
> - If T is char, then use new Character(x).
> - If T is byte, short, or int, then use new Integer(x).
> - If T is long, then use new Long(x).
> - If T is float, then use new Float(x).
> - If T is double, then use new Double(x).
>
> This reference value is then converted to type String by string conversion.
>
> Now only reference values need to be considered:
>
> - If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
> - Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the toString method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the toString method is null, then the string "null" is used instead.

In your case, it's the final bullet point in section 5.1.11 that applies.

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't have anything to do with `this`. It's more about how `+` works with strings.

The `+` operator, when one of the operands is a string and the other is not, it will try to convert the other operand into a string. For example:

```
"My age is: " + 30
```

It will try to convert 30 into a string. This can be done by

```
"My age is: " + (new Integer(30)).toString()
```

The situation is exactly the same in your case. Your expression:

```
 "The constructor for this is"+this
```

The second operand of `+` is not a string, so the compiler tries to convert `this` into a string. So `toString` is called:

```
"The constructor for this is"+this.toString()
```

`toString` is usually how you convert any reference type to a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent any object as a string, toString() method comes into existence.

The toString() method returns the string representation of the object.

If you print any object, java compiler internally invokes the toString() method on the object. So overriding the toString() method, returns the desired output, it can be the state of an object etc. depends on your implementation.